# Problem loading external dependency in CMake using FetchContent_Declare: "No Download Info Given"

Tags: c++, cmake, box2d

I have a fairly simple `CMAKE` project (generated by QT if it's relevant), and I'm trying to include an external library, `box2d`, in the build. It keeps failing with

```
error: No download info given for 'box2d-populate' and its source directory: <build_dir>/_deps/box2d-src is not an existing non-empty directory.  
Please specify one of: * SOURCE_DIR with an existing non-empty directory * DOWNLOAD_COMMAND * URL * GIT_REPOSITORY * SVN_REPOSITORY * HG_REPOSITORY * CVS_REPOSITORY and CVS_MODULE 
CMakeLists.txt:15 (ExternalProject_Add)
```

If I take out the FetchContent pieces it compiles fine. I've specified an existing non-empty Git repository I think, so I'm not sure what else to do. My CMake file is below.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(ExternalProject REQUIRED)
include(FetchContent REQUIRED)
find_package(Git REQUIRED) // this is the line it's complaining about

FetchContent_Declare(
    box2d
    Git_REPOSITORY https://github.com/erincatto/box2d.git
    GIT_TAG 9ebbbcd960ad424e03e5de6e66a40764c16f51bc # release-2.4.1
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(box2d)

target_link_libraries(A9_QTPies_Fall2021_CS3505 PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets PRIVATE box2d)
```

Comment: The proper option is `GIT_REPOSITORY`, not a `Git_REPOSITORY` one.

Comment: Thank you! Silly little typos can trip you up sometimes.